# Could not load type 'MarshalByRefType' from assembly 'CLRviaCSharp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Tags: c#-4.0, appdomain

This was the code present in book **CLR via C# 3e (Microsoft)**
But it is giving error during runtime

> TypeLoadException was unhandled Could not load type 'MarshalByRefType'
>   from assembly 'CLRviaCSharp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'.

Except the method 'Main', all code is of the book mentioned above.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Threading;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Remoting;

namespace CLRviaCSharp
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Marshalling();
        }

        private static void Marshalling()
        {
            // Get a reference to the AppDomain that that calling thread is executing in
            AppDomain adCallingThreadDomain = Thread.GetDomain();
            // Every AppDomain is assigned a friendly string name (helpful for debugging)
            // Get this AppDomain’s friendly string name and display it
            String callingDomainName = adCallingThreadDomain.FriendlyName;
            Console.WriteLine("Default AppDomain’s friendly name={0}", callingDomainName);
            // Get & display the assembly in our AppDomain that contains the ‘Main’ method
            String exeAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().FullName;
            Console.WriteLine("Main assembly={0}", exeAssembly);
            // Define a local variable that can refer to an AppDomain
            AppDomain ad2 = null;
            // *** DEMO 1: Cross-AppDomain Communication using Marshal-by-Reference ***
            Console.WriteLine("{0}Demo #1", Environment.NewLine);
            // Create new AppDomain (security & configuration match current AppDomain)
            ad2 = AppDomain.CreateDomain("AD #2", null, null);
            MarshalByRefType mbrt = null;
            // Load our assembly into the new AppDomain, construct an object, marshal
            // it back to our AD (we really get a reference to a proxy)
            mbrt = (MarshalByRefType)
            ad2.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(exeAssembly, "MarshalByRefType");
            Console.WriteLine("Type={0}", mbrt.GetType()); // The CLR lies about the type
            // Prove that we got a reference to a proxy object
            Console.WriteLine("Is proxy={0}", RemotingServices.IsTransparentProxy(mbrt));
            // This looks like we’re calling a method on MarshalByRefType but, we’re not.
            // We’re calling a method on the proxy type. The proxy transitions the thread
            // to the AppDomain owning the object and calls this method on the real object.
            mbrt.SomeMethod();
            // Unload the new AppDomain
            AppDomain.Unload(ad2);
            // mbrt refers to a valid proxy object; the proxy object refers to an invalid AppDomain
            try
            {
                // We’re calling a method on the proxy type. The AD is invalid, exception is thrown
                mbrt.SomeMethod();
                Console.WriteLine("Successful call.");
            }
            catch (AppDomainUnloadedException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed call.");
            }

            // *** DEMO 2: Cross-AppDomain Communication using Marshal-by-Value ***
            Console.WriteLine("{0}Demo #2", Environment.NewLine);
            // Create new AppDomain (security & configuration match current AppDomain)
            ad2 = AppDomain.CreateDomain("AD #2", null, null);
            // Load our assembly into the new AppDomain, construct an object, marshal
            // it back to our AD (we really get a reference to a proxy)
            mbrt = (MarshalByRefType)
            ad2.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(exeAssembly, "MarshalByRefType");
            // The object’s method returns a COPY of the returned object;
            // the object is marshaled by value (not be reference).
            MarshalByValType mbvt = mbrt.MethodWithReturn();
            // Prove that we did NOT get a reference to a proxy object
            Console.WriteLine("Is proxy={0}", RemotingServices.IsTransparentProxy(mbvt));
            // This looks like we’re calling a method on MarshalByValType and we are.
            Console.WriteLine("Returned object created " + mbvt.ToString());
            // Unload the new AppDomain
            AppDomain.Unload(ad2);
            // mbvt refers to valid object; unloading the AppDomain has no impact.
            try
            {
                // We’re calling a method on an object; no exception is thrown
                Console.WriteLine("Returned object created " + mbvt.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Successful call.");
            }
            catch (AppDomainUnloadedException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed call.");
            }

            // DEMO 3: Cross-AppDomain Communication using non-marshalable type ***
            Console.WriteLine("{0}Demo #3", Environment.NewLine);
            // Create new AppDomain (security & configuration match current AppDomain)
            ad2 = AppDomain.CreateDomain("AD #2", null, null);
            // Load our assembly into the new AppDomain, construct an object, marshal
            // it back to our AD (we really get a reference to a proxy)
            mbrt = (MarshalByRefType)
            ad2.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(exeAssembly, "MarshalByRefType");
            // The object’s method returns an non-marshalable object; exception
            NonMarshalableType nmt = mbrt.MethodArgAndReturn(callingDomainName);
            // We won’t get here...
        }
    }

    // Instances can be marshaled-by-reference across AppDomain boundaries
    public sealed class MarshalByRefType : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public MarshalByRefType()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ctor running in {1}",
            this.GetType().ToString(), Thread.GetDomain().FriendlyName);
        }
        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Executing in " + Thread.GetDomain().FriendlyName);
        }
        public MarshalByValType MethodWithReturn()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Executing in " + Thread.GetDomain().FriendlyName);
            MarshalByValType t = new MarshalByValType();
            return t;
        }
        public NonMarshalableType MethodArgAndReturn(String callingDomainName)
        {
            // NOTE: callingDomainName is [Serializable]
            Console.WriteLine("Calling from ‘{0}’ to ‘{1}’.",
            callingDomainName, Thread.GetDomain().FriendlyName);
            NonMarshalableType t = new NonMarshalableType();
            return t;
        }
    }
    // Instances can be marshaled-by-value across AppDomain boundaries
    [Serializable]
    public sealed class MarshalByValType : Object
    {
        private DateTime m_creationTime = DateTime.Now; // NOTE: DateTime is [Serializable]
        public MarshalByValType()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ctor running in {1}, Created on {2:D}",
            this.GetType().ToString(),
            Thread.GetDomain().FriendlyName,
            m_creationTime);
        }
        public override String ToString()
        {
            return m_creationTime.ToLongDateString();
        }
    }
    // Instances cannot be marshaled across AppDomain boundaries
    // [Serializable]
    public sealed class NonMarshalableType : Object
    {
        public NonMarshalableType()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Executing in " + Thread.GetDomain().FriendlyName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the CreateInstanceAndUnwrap calls you need to specify the fully qualified name of the type. Try "CLRviaCSharp.MarshalByRefType".

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. Thanks allot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you useAppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap method, you should pass a type's full name to the typeName parameter.
So, replace

```
ad2.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(exeAssembly, "MarshalByRefType");
```

with

```
ad2.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(exeAssembly, typeof(MarshalByRefType).FullName);
```